# Json with SSL on android

Tags: php, android, json, ssl

WHen I use SSL with Json on android, the request sent cannot be parsed correctly on the web server running PHP. Json works fine without SSL.
Particularly when I try to get $_POST elements it fails to find any.

// start of SSL part

```
  HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();//universal

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier((X509HostnameVerifier) hostnameVerifier);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", (SocketFactory) socketFactory, 443));
        SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(client.getParams(), registry);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, client.getParams());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
```

//end of SSL part

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean the request can not be parsed correctly?  If you could post some examples of the intended result and the actual result.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != ''){}  Without SSL, the tag can be read, but with SSL on, this is false. Somehow the transmitted data is changed during SSL encryption/decryption

Comment: possible duplicate of [$_POST values gone after SSL turned on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456533/post-values-gone-after-ssl-turned-on)

Answer (score 1):

Some code on Android side would help. So until you post some I would guess you have problems with SSL certification. You might check out this for help on that.

http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

Edit: sry just saw you edited your post with some code.

Comment: Maybe I found something... Which version of PHP are you using. It might be PHP bug:

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/ssl-no-post-values-89580.html

Comment: The php version is 5.2.17.   I think it's the certificate problem.

Comment: Well then, try is the way I posted above with the Keystore.

Comment: Tried it. The SSL exception is gone now. But the web server still cannot get the $_POST values. Is it a problem with the data not being (base64) encoded before transmission?

Comment: It should not be a problem. Except your server neeeds base64 encoded date and/or credentials.

you maybe need to set HTTPPost Headers like:

httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);

And try to send your json as new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");

Comment: It is still not working well. I tried with HttpGet and it works. Just not with HttpPost. file_get_contents('php://input') returns nothing.