# $_POST values gone after SSL turned on

Tags: php, android, json, ssl

In android, I try to send to the web server in a json structure. It works fine with http. But with https, $_POST values pairs are gone. In PHP, var_dump $_POST returns array(0)
However,HttpGet works well with both http and https.

```
        MyHttpClient httpClient = new MyHttpClient(context);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: yes, you have found a bug in php that no one else ever has -or- its your code. guess which?

Comment: Maybe your POST request gets redirected somehow and then it's loosing the post data?

Comment: If I set HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false); Then the page returns "Temporary broken link fixed"

Answer (score 2):

> If I set HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false); Then the page
>   returns "Temporary broken link fixed"

It sounds like you're sending your request to an `http://` URL and counting on a redirection (possibly via `mod_rewrite` or something similar such as a redirection in the PHP code itself) to turn your page into `https`.

This mode of operation first makes the plain HTTP request to the server, which then tells the client that the resource has moved to the `https://` address. In turn, if the automatic redirection is activated, the client makes a second request.

According to [the HTTP specification, for status codes 301 or 302](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) (which are used for the redirection),

> If the 301/302 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Most browsers interpret this as "if the first request was a POST, don't re-send the data for the redirected request, but make the second request a GET anyway." This would explain why you lose any POSTed body for the second attempt.

Note that, for the reasons explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105894/372643), over-reliance on rewrite/redirects to turn an `http://` request into an `https://` request should be considered bad practice.

Comment: I tried to type the https URL in the browser and it redirects me to a different link. I changed the URL to the redirected URL in java and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch [raw post data](http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-raw-post-data-in-php/) in php.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: There is nothing. I saved $data into the error log: $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
 error_log($data,0);

Comment: If $_REQUEST also is not getting anything then search for problem in java or url. + try to use some kind of log file instead of error_log() because maybe there can be apache configuration problem.