# HTTPS/PHP/NGINX: php://input data is NULL when HTTPS is enabled

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, https

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750257/enable-https-on-yii-1-and-nginx?noredirect=1#comment96283748_54750257). I found that when I checked my HTTPRequest on my YII that `Yii::app()->request` uses either `file_get_contents('php://input')` or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` to get the request from the front-end. This mechanism works when SSL is disabled yet when enabled, the post data disappears. I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456533/post-values-gone-after-ssl-turned-on) but there has been no concrete solution though there is an answer that discourages that use of a 302 redirect when forcing http to https. I need this mechanism on my api server to redirect http to https. How can I allow the redirection of http to https without losing post data? My nginx config is found on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54750257/enable-https-on-yii-1-and-nginx?noredirect=1#comment96283748_54750257).

I hope this gets resolved once and for all because I've spent more than a week stuck on this problem.

Comment: The solution is to NOT redirect HTTP to HTTPS.  Why send the user to HTTP if you want them to go to HTTPS?

Comment: You cannot redirect with data in the body. The body data will be lost. Usually when dealing with this on a web-app we do JavaScript trickery to force the browser to resubmit the body instead of sending a redirect response however since this is an API you can't do this.The solution is to stop forcing a redirect on API routes and ask your API consumers to switch to HTTPS and accept that ones that don't switch will not be secured.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect http to https, you have to update your nginx conf file.

Nginx should listen to http :

```
    server {
            listen          80;
            server_name     api.test.com;
            return 301 https://api.test.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen          443 ssl http2;
            server_name     api.test.com;

            root /var/apps/myapp/current/workspace/api;
            ...
```

The `http2` is optional